# Designing a Notification system

Tags: php, database

Looking into how to create a notification system like facebook.  I have a few ideas on what to possible do, but my friend said something about Graphs being of use?  I am working in PHP, but plan to switch to Python eventually to make an more efficient system with faster response times and such.

I can't provide too many details, because I don't really know what I am looking for yet.  Any suggestions on how to make something that is fast and scalable would be awesome.  I don't mind doing research on data structures if I am given the info on which ones to look into.

Thanks :)

EDIT: Ok, so maybe I wasn't clear on what I am trying to find out.  I need help on figuring out the database/storage structure on how to implement this.  I know i can use a lot of AJAX calls and such to get the information, but I want to know how to scale this properly on the size of millions.

Comment: What are the ideas you're having?

Comment: As far as I know, server-side JS like [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) is best for such things. I didn't have much experience with it so I can't say anything more, but look into that direction.

Comment: It doesn't matter what back-end language you would use, speed is dependent in your logic and coding knowledge. Use a lot of AJAX calls just like what FB is doing. Pass/receive data to/from database using JSON.

Comment: thanks for the downvote friend, I was merely trying to help you..

Comment: I didn't downvote anything, lol.  Someone else was nice enough to run through my question and all of the comments and downvote them all.  I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a notification system on my website.
 I use jquery and ajax. It pulls all of the information from php pages through out my server and doesn't need to refresh the page to get the newest information.

Like @Prody said make a small working system and then add stuff to it, and then optimize it, thats what I did and It worked out very well.

I suggest to make a mock up (of the design) first and them think what do I want it to do? Second try to build them into it and then try it if you don't like it then try again? Thats what I did but is still have quite a lot more to do.

if you must know I sent a ajax request every 3 seconds to get friend requests and emails and other notification's

And also this isn't a real question and will probably get minus votes because it's not a 'real question'

Comment: Can you tell me what kind of database/structure you are using for this?  I don't really know how to plan it out.

Comment: Yer i was in the same 'boat so to speak' as you when I started i just went with what I was most familiar with so i just used quite a lot of different MySQL structures (which are usually long texts and boolean)  i have a few different php pages which i get the information out so like i have one table for friend requests and one table for emails and one table for user posts and so on.

Comment: So you don't have any special kind of structures, just a bunch of smaller notification tables and select from all of them?  I guess you delete the notifications after a while?  Or do you just keep them stored?

Comment: no i don't really have any special kind of structure i just have a bunch of tables and then i just select data from them and display them to the user and also i keep the data until the user decides on removing them it is totally up to the user if he want's to remove them. For example the friend request is shown on the notification and then when he clicks on the accept or deny button it will vanish from the user but in the data base it just changes one of the variables and then the user is now friends with him or her and can chose to remove him or her as a friend when ever

Comment: Gotcha, interesting idea on friend requests, but ok.  Thanks for the help :)

Comment: yer it was the easiest way (well i thought) of showing my example :-D

Answer (score 1):

From what you're saying it seems you're working on something new.

From personal experience, you should try to get something working as soon as possible, and optimize later. This way you have something a lot faster and you reduce the risk of losing interest in the project.

Donald Knuth made the following two statements on optimization:

> "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time:
>   premature optimization is the root of all evil".

Just write your notification system storage-agnostic, for now store them as relations in a DB table, and replace with something more efficient in the future, if it ever comes to that.

You should not spend too much effort on optimization in the prototyping stage.

Comment: I agree, optimization issues should be dealt with as you go along. Facebook and other high-traffic sites did not create custom databases and handlers in the prototyping stages but later on when gigantic amount of traffic are hitting their servers. They also use CDN's to further redirect the flow of traffic somewhere else, just like the real-world highways where traffic is being redirected in other roads.

Comment: Interesting information.  Thanks :)